# why fstream zero errno in the destructor function

Tags: c++, exception, fstream, errno

the sample code is like this:

```
void testFuncErrno()
{
    fstream fstr;
    fstr.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
    try
    {
        fstr.open("/mnt/virtualfs/test.ss", ofstream::out);
        fstr << "test" << endl;
    }
    catch(std::ifstream::failure e)
    {
        cout << "func catch errno is:" << errno << ":" << strerror(errno) << endl;
        cout << "good?" << (fstr.good()?"yes":"no") << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    try
    {
        errno = 0;
        testFuncErrno();
        cout << "0 st errno is:" << errno << ":" << strerror(errno) << endl;
    }
    catch(std::ifstream::failure e)
    {
        cout << "catch errno is:" << errno << ":" << strerror(errno) << endl;
    }
    pause();
    return 0;
}
```

when the disk is full, i want to catch the errno, but it seems the errno will be set to zero when the function ended. I use ddd to trace the source code, and found some comments as below, but from the errno description:

**errno is set to zero at program startup, and any function of the standard C library can modify its value to some value different from zero, generally to signal specific categories of error (no library function sets its value back to zero once changed).**

it makes me a little confuse, why the close will set errno to zero?

```
  __basic_file<char>* 
  __basic_file<char>::close()
  { 
    __basic_file* __ret = static_cast<__basic_file*>(NULL);
    if (this->is_open())
      {
    int __err = 0;
    if (_M_cfile_created)
      {
        **// In general, no need to zero errno in advance if checking
        // for error first. However, C89/C99 (at variance with IEEE
        // 1003.1, f.i.) do not mandate that fclose must set errno
        // upon error.**
        errno = 0;
        do
          __err = fclose(_M_cfile);
        while (__err && errno == EINTR);
      }
    _M_cfile = 0;
    if (!__err)
      __ret = this;
      }
    return __ret;
  }
```

Comment: well, i also test fstream::close() function in a normal case, and it do set the errno to zero. But i have to catch this errno in my program to send out the error of running out of the disk space.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to Set errno to zero before calling a library function known to set errno, and check errno only after the function returns a value indicating failure. This is because the value of errno may be set to nonzero by a C standard library function call whether or not there is an error, provided the use of errno is not documented in the description of the function.

So if you initialise errno only at the start of the program, then there is no guarantee that the error value is set by which function call.

Setting error to 0 just before calling fclose() confirms that the value that errno is having is set by fclose() and no other function.

You may find below discussion of use:
https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6619179

Comment: Setting it to zero is poor practice. What is good practice is not testing `errno` unless you *know* there has been an immediately prior error, which is invariable signalled by the system call concerned returning -1.